# laravel scout and meilisearch filter and sort desc between two created_at filed date

Tags: laravel, full-text-search, laravel-scout, meilisearch

i want to filter some data between two date in created_at column and sort all by created_at

i don't have timestamp

My Code

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('2022-02-01')->startOfDay();
$endDate =  Carbon::parse('2022-02-15')->endOfDay();

    $messages = MessagesArch::search($myQuery)->query(function($q)  use ($startDate,$endDate) {
        return $q->whereBetween("created_at", [$startDate,$endDate]);
    })->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

how i can do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way:

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('2022-02-01')->startOfDay();
$endDate =  Carbon::parse('2022-02-15')->endOfDay();

$messages = MessagesArch::whereBetween("created_at", [$startDate,$endDate])->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: for basic yes but I wanna use meilisearch